# How to only make certain columns editable in a table in APEX ORACLE

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm trying to make a interactive grid that allows users to update certain tables depending on the permission/privilege they have. Currently, there is an updatable table in APEX, but it allows for the user to edit every column. Is there a way to not allow the user to edit certain columns in APEX ORACLE? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Two simple options I can think of: navigate to column's properties and

- set item type to "Display only", or
- scroll down as set it to be "Read only" and specify some condition (the most obvious one is "Always")

Comment: I dont see these options

Comment: Look closer ... Properties are in the 3rd, the rightmost column in Apex. Type is the second property. By default, it is probably set to "Text field" - change it to "Display only". Scroll properties down and you'll see the "Read only" section.

Comment: I need to insert first for all columns but Edit after insert for some columns after insert how can I do that please ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to go to Columns , expand, select the column that you want and set it to Display Only.

Comment: Glad i could help @Jason

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to post an answer here in case somebody else was looking for what I was when I found this.
If you want to make sure users can not change some columns but they can change others and that they can still add new rows.

You need to set each row you want to make not editable to read only when item is not null, type in the name of the row into the Item query and then also check that you want to do this for each row.